# Tensorflow Estimator self repair training on overfitting

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having some learning experience on tensorflows estimator api. Doing some classification task on a small dataset with tensorflow's  tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier (I know there is  tf.estimator.DNNClassifier but I have to work on tensorflow 1.2) I get the [accuracy graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxvXu.png) on my test dataset. I wonder why there are these negative peaks. 
I thought they could occur because of overfitting and self repairing. The next datapoint after the peak seems to have the same value as the point before.

I tried to look into the code to find any proof that estimator's train function has such a mechanism but did not find any.

So, is there such a mechanism or are there other possible explanations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the Estimator's train functions has any such mechanism.

Some possible theories:

- Does your training restart anytime? Its possible that if you have some Estimated Moving Average (EMA) in your model, upon restart the moving average has to be recomputed.
- Is your input data randomized? If not, its possible that a patch of input data is all misclassified, and again the EMA is possibly smoothing out.

This is pretty mysterious to me. If you do find out what the real issue is please do share!